# How do you mock expected REST API calls in a REACT frontend application for development?

Tags: reactjs

This is quite a newbie question. I have a frontend that I'm developing locally (localhost:5000) and I have an API that's guarded by some authentication mechanism. In an ideal world when this frontend's deployed there should be no problems hitting said API as the browser will have all the necessary session/cookies (api is deployed to foo.com/api/v1 frontend will be deployed to foo.com/index let's say)

At the moment it doesn't seem like I can query the API so I'm building my React components like this:

```
class EntityTypeSelector extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            error: null,
            isLoaded: false,
            items: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("/api/entity_types",)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(
                (result) => {
                    this.setState({
                        isLoaded: true,
                        items: result
                    });
                },
                (error) => {
                    // This is a hard coded list for dev purposes until we figure out another way
                    this.setState({
                        isLoaded: true,
                        items: [
                            {
                                "id": 2,
                                "label": "FOO"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 1,
                                "label": "BAR"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 3,
                                "label": "BIZ"
                            }
                        ],
                        error
                    });
                }
            )
    }

    render() {
        const dropDownSelection = []
        const {error, isLoaded, items} = this.state;
        for (const [index, value] of items.entries()) {
            dropDownSelection.push(<option entity_type_id={value["id"]}>{value["label"]}</option>)
        }


        if (!isLoaded) {
            return <div>Loading...</div>;
        } else {
            return (
                <Form.Group>
                    <Form.Control as="select">
                        <option>Entity Type</option>
                        {dropDownSelection}
                    </Form.Control>
                </Form.Group>
            ) // TODO add an event listener that calls something when this changes
        }
    }
}
```

But this feels quite... dirty. What's the right approach to developing this? Do I need to spin up my own api under localhost?

Comment: Check mswjs lib.

Answer (score 0):

What we do at work is, we use Redux to hold our application state, and Redux Sagas to do all fetches. We then mock the global state in our tests.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest while testing you can comment the fetch call inside componentDidMount and try to just update the state within setTimeout.
e.g

```
this.setState({
    isLoaded: false,
    items: [],
})

setTimeout(()=>{
   this.setState({
    isLoaded: false,
    data: <mockedData>
   })
}, 1000);
```

Once happy with testing just get rid the above one.

Comment: What's the general practice in keeping this code in "production" code though? Once this loads into prod we'll end up bundling this test code as part of it as well. That's my issue.